# Two code to run with Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Tags: excel, vba

I have two codes to run with (Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range))

When I run the developer One of the codes (for calendar) is working while the other is not.
The other code that doesn't work is for creating multi-selection from the drop-down list
Although it works successfully without the other code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Selection Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim Cal As Shape
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Cal = Shapes("Calendar")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Cal Is Nothing Then 'Shape Deleted
        Application.EnableEvents = False
         On Error Resume Next
        Application.Undo
        On Error GoTo 0
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("S4,S6")) Is Nothing Then 'Change this to any cell (or cells) you would like to have the Pop-Up Calendar Appear
        CheckForSheet
        CalendarShow
     Else:
        CheckForSheet
        CalendarHide
    End If

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.adress = "$t$2" Or Target.adress = "$u$2" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & vbNewLine & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `Worksheet_Selection Change` is not a valid event name?  For the dropdown list you need the `Change` event though, not `SelectionChange` so those two blcks of code don't belong in the same event handler.

Comment: OH, I got that ,THank you ,it works now